# Agrupar arrays com mesmo Id

Tags: php, json, laravel, foreach

**Estou fazendo um foreach, onde agrupo os valores por id,
e me encontro com o seguinte problema:
Meu foreach esta atualmente assim**

```
foreach ($skuProduto as $skuProduto ) { 

            foreach ($skuProduto->variacao as $variacao ) { 

                $variacoes[] = [

                     "name" => $variacao ->valor, 
                     "value" => $variacao ->item
                 ];

            $data[] = [             
            "Id"=>  $variacao->id,
            "Attributes"=> [ 
                 [
                    $variacoes,

                 ]

                ]
            ];

          }

        }
```

**e me retorna o valor da seguinte maneira**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "001",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Preto",
                "value": "Cor"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "002",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Preto",
                "value": "Cor"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "001",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "name": "tamanho",
                "value": "10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "002",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "name": "tamanho",
                "value": "5"
            }
        ]
    },
```

**E preciso que ele retorne agrupando os valores de acordo com o id 
desta maneira**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "001",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Preto",
                "value": "Cor"
            },
            {
                "name": "tamanho",
                "value": "10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "002",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Preto",
                "value": "Cor"
            },
            {
                "name": "tamanho",
                "value": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**qual a maneira correta de fazer o foreach para que os valores retornem corretamente**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
$arraySku = array();
$indice = 0;
foreach ($skuProduto as $skuProduto ) { 
  foreach ($skuProduto as $key => $variacao){
    $arraySku[$indice]['id] = $key;
    $variacoes[] = [
        "name" => $variacao ->valor, 
        "value" => $variacao ->item
    ];
    $arraySku[$indice]['Attributes'] = $variacoes;
    $indice++;
  }
}

$encodedSku = json_encode($arraySku);
```